# NSTableView Header gets blurred when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

When I move the horizontal scroller randomly for sometime continuously,sometimes it is observed the NSTableView Header gets blurred. When clicked somewhere else,the header becomes normal again.This issue occurs occassionally not always.

Comment: So why to worry about the un-wanted feature from Apple?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Cocoa